# Java android Open Street map doesn't display map

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have some problem on API 22 it works good but on API 23 I don't see a map, I can only see a marker which I put. On old version of android it works.

In log i have :

```
Thread-27428(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
Thread-27428(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
Thread-27428(ApacheHTTPLog):getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
Thread-27428(ApacheHTTPLog):Smart Bonding Setting is false
Thread-27428(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Setting is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
```

AndroidOpenStreetMapViewActivity.java

```
public class AndroidOpenStreetMapViewActivity extends Activity {

    private MapView myOpenMapView;
    private MapController myMapController;

    ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myOpenMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
        myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myMapController = (MapController) myOpenMapView.getController();
        myMapController.setZoom(2);
            //--- Create Another Overlay for multi marker
        anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "0, 0", "0, 0", new GeoPoint(0, 0)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "US", "US", new GeoPoint(38.883333, -77.016667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "China", "China", new GeoPoint(39.916667, 116.383333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", new GeoPoint(51.5, -0.116667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "Germany", "Germany", new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "Korea", "Korea", new GeoPoint(38.316667, 127.233333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "India", "India", new GeoPoint(28.613333, 77.208333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "Russia", "Russia", new GeoPoint(55.75, 37.616667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "France", "France", new GeoPoint(48.856667, 2.350833)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
                "Canada", "Canada", new GeoPoint(45.4, -75.666667)));

        ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay
                = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
                this, anotherOverlayItemArray, null);
        myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
        //---

        //Add Scale Bar
        ScaleBarOverlay myScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);
        myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(myScaleBarOverlay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time please mention the library you are using, in this case `osmdroid`. I added it to your tags.

Comment: and what version of osmdroid.

Comment: @spy  : 'osmdroid-android', version: '4.2'

Answer (score 1):

I add check WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when I agree it works good

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to request runtime permissions from the user if the target API is 23 or higher. See the sample osmdroid app for an example doing so here

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/intro/PermissionsFragment.java

or readthe android guide here on this here
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html